# SQL Server High CPU Usage

Tags: sql-server, cpu-usage, etl

I'm getting an issue during an ETL of client data where SQL chews up 100% CPU on my dev server. This only happens on occasion, and I have found the particular part of the SP that's causing it, but not sure why it's using so much CPU.

The LoadId and ClientId are both input variables for the SP. Basically, I am trying to find if any of the objects IDs in the Staging table (newly loaded data) match with existing objects (for a particular client), and also check in the Validation table (data gets a validation check before it gets processed) for any errors.

```
SELECT  src.Id ,
            o.Id ,
            CASE WHEN o.Id IS NULL THEN 0
                 ELSE 1
            END
    FROM    ObjectsStaging src
            LEFT OUTER JOIN client.Objects o ON src.Id = o.UniqueId
    WHERE   src.LoadId = 22
            AND ( o.ClientId IS NULL
                  OR o.ClientId = 3
                )
            AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                             FROM   dbo.ValidationLog v
                             WHERE  v.LoadId = 22
                                    AND v.RowId = src.RowId )
```

Comment: What does query analyzer say?

Comment: please post the entire sp as there can be many possible reasons for this

Comment: Query Analyser doesn't make any suggestions. It says there's a 70% cost for the Index Seek on the Objects table.

Comment: Also, I'm not posting the whole SP, as it's not needed. I can reproduce the issue just by running this query. The objects table has about 2.5mil rows.

Comment: Are src.Id and o.UniqueId the exact same data type?

Comment: Yes, both NVARCHAR(4000)

Comment: Couple of things to try; You say your IDs are NVARCHAR(4000) - that seems strange, so if possible, then just to investigate - try to add id's which are int or similar and join on those. Also - try to filter your ObjectStaging completely (the not exists) before left joining using either commontable expressions or similar. Also - check your statistics are up to date and there's relationships between the join conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this but change the v.PK to a Non nullible column in the V table.

```
SELECT  src.Id ,
            o.Id ,
            CASE WHEN o.Id IS NULL THEN 0
                 ELSE 1
            END
    FROM    ObjectsStaging src
            LEFT OUTER JOIN client.Objects o ON src.Id = o.UniqueId
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ValidationLog v on v.LoadId = 22 AND v.RowId = src.RowId
    WHERE   src.LoadId = 22
            AND ( o.ClientId IS NULL
                  OR o.ClientId = 3
                )
            AND v.PK is null -- V.loadid is null ?   --(same as not exists)
```